# Depth map from a stereo camera

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, camera, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to adapt the RGBDSLAM node that works with the kinect to make it work with my stereo camera. From the Bumblebee2 i can access to the rectified images, the disparity map and the pointcloud using the streo_image_proc node. The RGBDSLAM needs a pointcloud, an rgb image and a depth map.

How can i access to the depth map from my stereo camera ? does the the stereo_image_proc node do it ? Because i didn't find any topic that publishes this depth map.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60156/depth-map-from-a-stereo-camera/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use use rgbdslam with a stereo camera directly. There are parameters called "wide_...", with which you can set the monochrome image and the cloud. For instance like that:

```
<param name="config/wide_topic"                    value="/camera/image_mono"/>
<param name="config/wide_cloud_topic"              value="/camera/points"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-02**:
And if no parameters ? How i can access to the depth image thank to the stereo camera ?